# Energy required to liquify gaseous oxygen?

Tags: pressure, cooling, compressed-gases, liquid

Does anyone know where I can find some documentation of a real-world liquification process, and the energy costs?

I can calculate the heat that must be removed from O<sub>2</sub> gas to get to liquid, but how would this translate to an amount of electricity (kWh) required to operate the cooling equipment?

I hope that my basic thermodynamics calculation are correct?

[image: Attached shows the heat that must be removed 1 mol O2 to liquify]

Comment: electricity costs vary by country, location and even time of day.

Comment: I mean how much electrical energy in kWh is required... e.g per mol O2 when you start with O2 at standard conditions
@SolarMike I edited to clarify

Comment: Ok, so what particular process and therefore cooling equipment are you using?

Comment: I'm not tied to a particular system, but rather looking at it from a theoretical perspective for modeling. So, I would start with the simplest available options. I read a bit online but could not easily find info.

Basically, I need a reasonable approximate electrical energy requirement for this liquification step so I can plug it into a model of a larger system.

Comment: @dlight To get the answer you want, you'll need to take the quotient of the "heat that must be removed" by the coefficient of performance of the cooling process, and I'm afraid you can't do that without specifying what cooling process you intend to use.  Even to set an upper bound on the coefficient of performance using the second law of thermodynamics, you'd need to specify the temperature of the coldest reservoir you've got available to which to dump the waste heat.

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenic_oxygen_plant

Comment: 300kW for 2 tons/day -  https://advancedtech.airliquide.com/liquid-oxygen-lox-plant

Comment: @PhilSweet awesome find, i wonder if the Air liquid link you sent is the power cost for taking in normal air to make pure O2. That is what is meant by cryogenic air separation plants right?

Im interested in liquefying an already pure O2 product. but still great find will read more about this thank you.

Comment: Okay, not everybody has a big tank O2 to start with. Sorry for going off on a tangent. What is the pressure of the O2 gas tank? You need to use a real gas model for the specific heat when the temps are near a phase change or the temp change is large.

Comment: https://www.conceptsnrec.com/blog/going-through-a-phase-modeling-phase-change-with-cubics,

Comment: Sorry for late answer.
The O2 stream is coming from the anode of an electrolytic cell. For my purpose I will assume that it is at 1 atm at 298K.  But in fact, It pretty easy to calculate the energy required to compress the gas, so starting pressure can be at any arbitrary value, I think

Comment: Since cryo air separation only has a few more steps to separate n2 and argon and reject co2 and volatiles, maybe i can consder that 300 kW for 2 tons/per day is close enough.

that gives me 0.11 kWh/mol O2 at that flow rate.I guess it would be less energy if I started with pure O2.

Answer (score 0):

From a physics standpoint, you need to consider your full cycle.

If you increase pressure by pumping in more molecules to a given volume or take a given set of molecules and reduce the volume makes a difference.  (Usually high pressure applications like this will end up on the given volume route due to space constraints.)  Pressure losses over check valves can have more than an insignificant bearing on easily compressible fluids such as gasses.  Compressing very slowly can be efficient but your industrial process will likely need to sacrifice a bit of efficiency to get a desired throughput.

Next up the actual removal of heat.  The compression causes the oxygen to increase in temperature.  Increased temperature means heat will naturally flow out into a reservoir of the pre-compression temperature, but this is usually too slow for industrial processes.  A heat pump of some sort would incur the remaining losses in bringing the compressed oxygen down to condensation temp for your pressure and removing energy at the rate desired for your process (this is where that kWh calculation comes in, but with the energy you put in for compression also included!).

Put both processes together and optimize to find an efficient target pressure and temperature.  (One determines the other from Oxygen's phase diagram).

Comment: thanks for the insight. I think in my case the rate limiting step will not be compression. So a slow compression is okay, to some extent. in terms of temperature and pressure, I have no constraint, just needs to be liquid. Indeed I have to calculate how the cooling system will work. I'm still not sure how to calculate it but will keep working on it.

Comment: The need to be liquid is the constraint- it makes the necessary pressure a function of temperature or the necessary temperature the function of pressure.  You can search for a "Oxygen phase diagram" - the curve between gas and liquid is what you are interested in.

Comment: yes I'm aware of phase diagrams. I tried to say that any point in liquid state is equivalent to me, I will want the minimal energy cost to liquefy.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate the required amount of electric energy with the coefficient of performance (COP) and Carnot.

At first you can assume an electric Carnot heat pump, which consumes thermal energy at low temperature as well as electric energy and discharges both at high temperature.

The effectiveness of a Carnot heat pump is expressed in terms of COP, which describes the ratio of useful cooling energy $Q_C$ to the work required to complete the cycle $W_{el}$, which is the electric energy you are looking for.

The COP of a Carnot heat pump is defined as:

$$
COP_{Carnot} = \frac{Q_C}{W_{el}} = \frac{T_L}{T_H - T_L}
$$

$T_L$ is the lowest temperature in your cycle and $T_H$ is the highest temperature in your cycle.

The Carnot heat pump is an ideal machine without any irreversibilities. Modern heat pumps achieve Carnot efficiencies of approx. $\eta_{Carnot}=0.5 \ldots 0.6$. Thus, you can calculate the electric energy required as follows:

$$
W_{el} = \frac{Q_C}{\eta_{Carnot} COP_{Carnot}}
$$